# How to toggle prepend in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle a css link using a jquery, via a single button.

Catch is, I want to do it in the target of an iframe.

So far I have the following code, which insets the link fine:

```
$("#custom").click(function() {
    $("#content").contents().find("head").prepend("<link href=\"../build/css/custom.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"custom-css\">");
});
```

This is activated by the following html:

```
<div class="toggle-custom">
<a target="custom" id="custom" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Toggle custom style</a>
</div>
<iframe id="content" src="carousel.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

I know that the way to remove it is:

```
$("#content").contents().find("#custom-css").remove();
```

But how can I toggle it from the same button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var contents = $("#content").contents();
var ccss = contents.find("head").find("#custom-css");
if(ccss.length){
    ccss.remove()
} else {
    contents.find("head").prepend("<link href=\"../build/css/custom.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"custom-css\">");
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but how do I toggle it from the same button?

Comment: @alias51 you want to remove it if it is present else add it

Comment: Yes, that's the question I'm asking. What's the code for this?

Comment: thanks, that loads the page with the style but doesn't remove it on toggle

Answer (score 0):

Put the link in the html, then toggle it on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#custom-css').hide();
    $("#custom").click(function() {
        $('#custom-css').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full syntax:

```
$("#custom").click(function() {
          var head = $("#content").contents().find("head");
    var ccss = head.find("#custom-css");
    if (ccss.length) {
        ccss.remove()
    } else {
        head.prepend("<link href=\"../build/css/custom.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"custom-css\">");
    }
});
```